# Exclude zero list elements in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `km2`. I am performing a list operation and generating a new list `Time`. However, I am getting an error because of the `0` element. I present the expected output.

```
km2=[0, 2.8945617583603203e-05, 0, 2.8964584076162397e-05, 2.8807838358146397e-05, 2.884599889020239e-05, 2.8869540930559196e-05]

Time=[-1/i for i in km2]
print(Time)
```

The error is

```
in <listcomp>
    Time=[-1/i for i in km2]

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

The expected output is

```
[0, -34547.54410099265, 0, -34524.92179312844, -34712.77461251153, -34666.85289028602, -34638.58335694811]
```

Comment: Well, you can't divide by 0, so you need to skip the element, when it is 0 to avoid the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle `0` separately with a conditional expression:

```py
Time = [-1/i if i != 0 else 0 for i in km2]
```

Alternatively, since `0` is considered falsy, `!= 0` can be omitted:

```py
Time = [-1/i if i else 0 for i in km2]
```

Comment: I really don't like the falsy fallback here. Not gonna dispute whether it works, but I think it obscures the intention that's driving the logic

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
Time=[-1/i for i in km2 if i != 0]
```